# Using Gnome Builder with Python

Tags: python, numpy, flatpak, gnome-builder

I am trying to create a Project with Gnome Builder in Python.
The documentation is very limited, but I **think** found out:

When you press the "build" button in Builder, it tries to build a flatpak and runs it.
This works for the initial project stub.
When i add a

```
import numpy
```

the project cannnot be run, because there is no numpy yet.
I **think** this has to be added in the .JSON File. I also **think** the meson file is only for "collecting" the .py sources for the flatpak-builder.
I followed the documentation on http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/python.html
and created a module for numpy with the flatpak-pip-generator.

My .JSON file now looks like this:

```
{
    "app-id": "de.gymlan.Plottler",
    "runtime": "org.gnome.Platform",
    "runtime-version": "3.32",
    "sdk": "org.gnome.Sdk",
    "command": "plottler",
    "finish-args": [
        "--share=network",
        "--share=ipc",
        "--socket=fallback-x11",
        "--socket=wayland",
        "--filesystem=xdg-run/dconf",
        "--filesystem=~/.config/dconf:ro",
        "--talk-name=ca.desrt.dconf",
        "--env=DCONF_USER_CONFIG_DIR=.config/dconf"
    ],
    "cleanup": [
        "/include",
        "/lib/pkgconfig",
        "/man",
        "/share/doc",
        "/share/gtk-doc",
        "/share/man",
        "/share/pkgconfig",
        "*.la",
        "*.a"
    ],
    "modules": [
        {
            "name": "plottler",
            "builddir": true,
            "buildsystem": "meson",
            "sources": [
                {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "file:///home/ulrich/Projekte/Plottler"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
      "name": "python3-numpy",
          "buildsystem": "simple",
          "build-commands": [
            "pip3 install --no-index --find-links=\"file://${PWD}\" --prefix=${FLATPAK_DEST} numpy"
          ],
          "sources": [
            {
            "type": "file",
            "url": "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/36/325b27ef698684c38b1fe2e546e2e7ef9cecd7037bcdb35c87efec4356af/numpy-1.17.2.zip",
            "sha256": "73615d3edc84dd7c4aeb212fa3748fb83217e00d201875a47327f55363cef2df"
             }
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But the build fails with an error from git, which I don't understand:

```
flatpak-builder --arch=x86_64 --ccache --force-clean --state-dir /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/flatpak-builder --download-only --disable-updates --stop-at=python3-numpy /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/projects/Plottler/flatpak/staging/x86_64-master /home/ulrich/Projekte/Plottler/de.gymlan.Plottler.json
Emptying app dir '/home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/projects/Plottler/flatpak/staging/x86_64-master'
Downloading sources
Fetching full git repo file:///home/ulrich/Projekte/Plottler
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Failed to download sources: module plottler: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 128 beendet
flatpak-builder --arch=x86_64 --ccache --force-clean --disable-updates --disable-download --state-dir /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/flatpak-builder --stop-at=python3-numpy /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/projects/Plottler/flatpak/staging/x86_64-master /home/ulrich/Projekte/Plottler/de.gymlan.Plottler.json
Starting build of de.gymlan.Plottler
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

(flatpak-builder:73): flatpak-builder-WARNING **: 16:45:17.109: Failed to get current git checksum: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 128 beendet
Cache miss, checking out last cache hit

(flatpak-builder:73): flatpak-builder-WARNING **: 16:45:17.109: rofiles-fuse not available, doing without
========================================================================
Building module plottler in /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/flatpak-builder/build/plottler-11
========================================================================
error: pathspec 'master' did not flatpak-builder --arch=x86_64 --ccache --force-clean --state-dir /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/flatpak-builder --download-only --disable-updates --stop-at=python3-numpy /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/projects/Plottler/flatpak/staging/x86_64-master /home/ulrich/Projekte/Plottler/de.gymlan.Plottler.json
Emptying app dir '/home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/projects/Plottler/flatpak/staging/x86_64-master'
Downloading sources
Fetching full git repo file:///home/ulrich/Projekte/Plottler
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Failed to download sources: module plottler: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 128 beendet
flatpak-builder --arch=x86_64 --ccache --force-clean --disable-updates --disable-download --state-dir /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/flatpak-builder --stop-at=python3-numpy /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/projects/Plottler/flatpak/staging/x86_64-master /home/ulrich/Projekte/Plottler/de.gymlan.Plottler.json
Starting build of de.gymlan.Plottler
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

(flatpak-builder:73): flatpak-builder-WARNING **: 16:45:17.109: Failed to get current git checksum: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 128 beendet
Cache miss, checking out last cache hit

(flatpak-builder:73): flatpak-builder-WARNING **: 16:45:17.109: rofiles-fuse not available, doing without
========================================================================
Building module plottler in /home/ulrich/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/flatpak-builder/build/plottler-11
========================================================================
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
Error: module plottler: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 1 beendet
match any file(s) known to git
Error: module plottler: Der Kindprozess wurde mit Status 1 beendet
```

(Last lines are german "child process failed")

Answer (score 2):

I found out myself:

The section of the packages must not added in the main JSON-file, but in separate files. flatpak-pip-generator.py creates the resource files for the modules and theses files have to be added from the main JSON document. Mine now looks like that:

```
{
    "app-id": "de.gymlan.Plottler",
    "runtime": "org.gnome.Platform",
    "runtime-version": "3.32",
    "sdk": "org.gnome.Sdk",
    "command": "plottler",
    "finish-args": [
        "--share=network",
        "--share=ipc",
        "--socket=fallback-x11",
        "--socket=wayland",
        "--filesystem=xdg-run/dconf",
        "--filesystem=~/.config/dconf:ro",
        "--talk-name=ca.desrt.dconf",
        "--env=DCONF_USER_CONFIG_DIR=.config/dconf"
    ],
    "cleanup": [
        "/include",
        "/lib/pkgconfig",
        "/man",
        "/share/doc",
        "/share/gtk-doc",
        "/share/man",
        "/share/pkgconfig",
        "*.la",
        "*.a"
    ],
    "modules": [
        "python3-numpy.json",
        "python3-matplotlib.json",
        "python3-pandas.json",
        {
            "name": "plottler",
            "builddir": true,
            "buildsystem": "meson",
            "sources": [
                {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "file:///home/ulrich/Projekte/Plottler"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

And the files "python3-*.json" reside the same directory.
So all I had to do is calling

```
$ ./flatpak-pip-generator.py numpy
$ ./flatpak-pip-generator.py matplotlib
$ ./flatpak-pip-generator.py pandas
```

in the projects directory and add the generated files to the projects JSON file.